# PHP: Add video tag to youtube link fron content

Tags: post, youtube, preg-replace

I have variable `$post->post_content` that return me detail of post and some video URL from YouTube.

I need to remove any text from `$post->post_content` else YouTube link, And add to YouTube likn this tag

```
<video>YouTube_URL</video>
```

the `content` like :-

```
At this instant, while Daggoo, on the summit of the head, was clearing the whip—which had somehow got foul of the great cutting tackles—a sharp cracking noise was heard; and to the unspeakable horror of all, one of the two enormous hooks suspending the head tore out, and with a vast vibration the enormous mass sideways swung, till the drunk ship reeled and shook as if smitten by an iceberg. The one remaining hook, upon which the entire strain now depended, seemed every instant to be on the point of giving way; an event still more likely from the violent motions of the head.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEreM0ZKY18
```

and some time like :-

```
أسر شعار اسبوعين الدولارات من, شرسة أعلنت اندلاع إذ هذا. وبعد الثالث أوكيناوا ما بين, الحصار الأمامية بـ عدد. ذات بقعة فمرّ إذ, أخذ كل بالحرب وسمّيت المانيا. و فصل بمباركة المقيتة, أملاً الحصار المتاخمة من عدد. بزمام أثره، التبرعات تم بعد, الجيش خصوصا كانتا ان دار.

    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEreM0ZKY18
```

My code:

```
$posts = query_posts('showposts='.$numposts.'&cat=19');
foreach ($posts as $post) { 
$postOutput1 = preg_replace('#<a[^>]+>([\r\n|\n]+)?<img[^>]+>([\r\n|\n]+)?<\/a>#','', $post->post_content);
$postOutput2 = preg_replace('@https?://(www\.)?youtube.com/.[^\s.,"\']+@i','', $postOutput1);
$postOutput = preg_replace('[youtube','', $postOutput2);
preg_match_all('@https?://(www\.)?youtube.com/.[^\s.,"\']+@i', $post->post_content, $matches);
foreach($matches as $match){
    echo "<video>$match</video>";
}}
```

How can do that.?

Comment: What does the variable look like? Can you paste the contents of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = "At this instan ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEreM0ZKY18"
$pattern = '/(http\S*)/im';
$array = array();
preg_match($pattern, $string, $array);
$link = $array[0];
print $link;
```